# Procedure with multiple transactions how to set the error message to the output parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In Sql Server 2008 R2, I am creating a procedure with multiple transactions in it. Try..Catch Block is used for each transaction. I use output parameter to catch the error code and message since it will be caught by the main program. But When there is errors the output parameter are not correct set to the error message and code, what is problem here?

```
create procedure xxx (@P_Return_Status  VARCHAR(1) OUTPUT, @P_Error_Code INT OUTPUT,)
AS 
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TR1
    .....
    COMMIT TRANSACTIOn TR1
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TR1
    END             
    Set @P_Error_Code = Error_Number();
    Set @P_Error_Messages = LEFT(ERROR_MESSAGE (), 2000)
  END CATCH

  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TR2
    .....
    COMMIT TRANSACTIOn TR2
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TR2
    END             
    Set @P_Error_Code = Error_Number();
    Set @P_Error_Messages = LEFT(ERROR_MESSAGE (), 2000)
  END CATCH
END
GO
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Aside: SQL Server doesn't support nested transactions. If your SP is called within a transaction then you may get results you don't like. Some suggested reading is [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/). You can use something like `declare @LocalTransaction as Bit = case when @@TranCount = 0 then 1 else 0 end;` at the start of an SP to check for existing transactions and decide whether or not to create and commit/rollback a local transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I just don't see the point of putting two transaction inside this one procedure, just put all of the statements in one transaction and commit it or rollback it.

if it does need to be in separate transactions put these both try...catch in two separate procedures and call one sp from another sp's try block.

```
create procedure xxx 
  @P_Return_Status      INT             OUTPUT
 ,@P_Error_Code         INT             OUTPUT
 ,@P_Error_Messages     VARCHAR(2000)   OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TR1

    /* put statements from both transaction here
         or
         statements for TR1
            AND
         call the procedure containing code for TR2
     */

    COMMIT TRANSACTIOn TR1
     SET @P_Return_Status = 1;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TR1
      END 

    Set @P_Error_Code = Error_Number();
    Set @P_Error_Messages = LEFT(ERROR_MESSAGE (), 2000)
    SET @P_Return_Status = 0;
  END CATCH

END
GO
```